# PeriodicSyc: How to resolve the pending promise?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, webapi

I want to implement a background sync using the [webapi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Periodic_Background_Synchronization_API) and I will need a couple of different implementations of it for specific background tasks like **sync, update check and other things**.
My idea was to create a class **BackgroundManager** where I could implement the WebApi and make my implementations inherit from it.

With this code, I can create an instance of the Update class that inherits the **subscribe**, **unsubscribe** and **getSubscriptions** from **BackgroundManager**.
The problem is that I cannot get a resolved promise, and I don't understand why.

[image: Creating a update instance of BackgroundManager]

```
class BackgroundManager {

    async subscribe() {
        const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
        const type = this.type;

        try {
            await registration.periodicSync.register(type, {
                minInterval: this.interval,
            });
        } catch {
            console.log('Periodic Sync could not be registered!');
        }
        return 'subscribed'
    }

    async unsubscribe() {
        const type = this.type;

        const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
        if ('periodicSync' in registration) {
            await registration.periodicSync.unregister(type);
        }
        return 'unsubscribed'
    }

    async getSubscriptions() {
        const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
        if ('periodicSync' in registration) {
            const tags = await registration.periodicSync.getTags();
            return tags;
        }
    }
}

class Update extends BackgroundManager{
    constructor(type) {
        super();
        this.type = type;
        this.interval = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    }

    update() {
        this.id = 'updating';
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not completely sure whether this idea is the best solution for what I am trying to do, so if anyone has a better solution, this is also welcome.

I just opted for this one because I thought that if my background services grow I will be able to easily implement new instances of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Periodic background sync, as currently implemented in Chrome, has a few preconditions, described in [this article](https://web.dev/periodic-background-sync/):

- It will only work if the progressive web app has been [installed](https://web.dev/customize-install/).
- It may be gated on the user [granting explicit permission](https://web.dev/periodic-background-sync/#permissions) for the installed PWA to use background sync.

If either of those conditions are not met, that might explain why you're having trouble using the feature.

Comment: I checked here and that was the reason why the code was not working.
Based on that I will not be able to use it because I cannot "force" the user to install the app. I will have to think of another solution.